# Estimate clan size

Tags: expected-value, puzzle

> The people in a country are partitioned into clans. In order to estimate the average size of a clan, a survey is conducted where $1000$ randomly selected people are asked to state the size of the clan to which they belong. How does one compute an estimate average clan size from the data collected?

Source: puzzledquant.com

My approach: I am thinking of using $E[X]$=$E[E[X|N]]$ where $X$ is size and $N$ is the clan I am currently in. But I am unsure how to proceed from here. Help.

Comment: Suppose a clan has probability $p_k$ of containing $k$ people, $k \geq 1$. Three questions: $1$. What would the average clan size be? $2$. Given that probability distribution, what would the probability $q_k$ be of a randomly selected person belonging to a clan of size $k$? $3$. Can you write the answer to question $1$ in terms of the answers to question $2$?

Comment: Imagine you have 100 persons in this country, and you can ask to every one the size of his clan. Imagine the real repartition is 10+10+10+20+50 : so you know that the answers will be 10 (30 times), 20 (20 times) and 50 (50 times) ; what is the formula to apply to obtain 5 (number of clans) ? And then, to obtain 20 (average size of a clan) ?

Comment: @BrianTung 1. This would be sum $k$*$p_k$

Comment: If total country is 100, and my clan is 20, I say : my clan is 20, or I say : total country is similar to 5 clans like mine.  So with previous example, the answers are 10 (30 times), 5 (20 times) and 2(50 times)

Comment: Another hint : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean

Comment: Please provide a full reference, including a link to the original source, not just the text of the domain name.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

$$n/\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{k_j}$$
Where

- n is the sample size
- $k_j$ is the survey answer obtained at j-th
  observation

### How to figure this out

Average clan size true value is

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^M k_i}{M}=\frac{N}{M}$$
where

- M is unknown quantity of groups
- N is unknown total amount of people on the island
- $k_i$ is unknown group size of distinct group i

If we just sum the survey answers for the whole population we will get

$$\sum_{j=1}^N k_j=\sum_{i=1}^M k_i*k_i = \sum_{i=1}^M k_j^2$$
As every group of size $k_i$ is reported precisely $k_i$ times in case of whole population.

Instead of summing it with Identity($k_i$) = $k_i$ we check if summing with
f($k_i$) = 1/$k_i$ will provide something more like $\frac{N}{M}$

$$\sum_{j=1}^N f(k_i)=\sum_{j=1}^N 1/k_i=\sum_{i=1}^M k_i*1/k_i=\sum_{i=1}^M 1 =M$$

This is how we can estimate the denominator of desired fraction. The nominator is estimated using sample size as usual.